# buildingTag() always returns false

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Whenever I try to create a conditional stage with `buildingTag()`, the stage always gets skipped, even when the current commit is a tag. Here is my Jenkinsfile:

```groovy
pipeline {
  agent {
    docker {
      image 'node:10'
    }

  }
  stages {
    stage('Build') {
      steps {
        sh 'yarn install'
        sh 'node scripts/build.js'
      }
    }
    stage('Lint') {
      steps {
        sh 'yarn lint'
      }
    }
    stage('Deploy') {
      when {
        buildingTag()
      }
      environment {
      }
      steps {
        sh 'node scripts/deploy.js'
        sh 'node scripts/publish.js'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is the commit showing in the console output from Jenkins equal the one you tagged? Usually the condition should work correctly

Comment: @mkemmerz The logs show `git checkout -f 8ce7cd6efc73d5632a089ae9ea992e075e2d784b` which is the correct commit.

Comment: Ok just to be sure - you have tagged it correctly?

Comment: @mkemmerz I'm using the `np` package to publishing the package, which also tags and pushes the commit to GitHub. Not sure there is a way to incorrectly tag a commit other than just not tagging it at all.

Answer (score 3):

Likely due to this bug:

https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-55987

Workaround is:

```
            when {
                expression {
                    return !isVersionTag(readCurrentTag())           
                }
            }
```

with:

```
def boolean isVersionTag(String tag) {
    echo "checking version tag $tag"

    if (tag == null) {
        return false
    }

    // use your preferred pattern
    def tagMatcher = tag =~ /\d+\.\d+\.\d+/

    return tagMatcher.matches()
}

// workaround https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-55987
def String readCurrentTag() {

    return sh(returnStdout: true, script: "git describe --tags").trim()           
}
```

Comment: This is a great answer, however I don't think it'll work for nested conditions. For example somewhere inside a `post { success { script { <here> `  since `when {` is meant as only a `stage { when {` sub value. :(

Comment: I don't get why you are using `!isVersionTag` instead of `isVersionTag`, what's with the negation?

Comment: it makes sense in a wider context I deleted from the example...

Answer (score 2):

`buildingTag()` requires that the `TAG_NAME` environment varible is set.

This is not set automatically in a simple (not multibranch) pipeline.

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    environment {
        // To get the tag like shown soru's answer:
        // TAG_NAME = sh(returnStdout: true, script: "git describe --tags").trim()

        // In my case I already have a tag saved as an environment variable:
        // gitlabBranch=refs/tags/tagname
        TAG_NAME = "${env.gitlabBranch.split('/')[2]}"
    }
    stages {
        stage('buildingTag') {
            when { buildingTag() }
            steps {
                echo 'buildingTag works here.'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also come across this problem. All you need to do enable `Advanced clone behaviours -> Fetch tags` in the project settings, and set `TAG_NAME` environment variable in the Jenkins file.

1- Advanced clone behaviours

[image]

2- Fetch tags

[image]

3- And set `TAG_NAME` variable in pipeline (`buildingTag` function requires this)

```
pipeline {
  environment {
    TAG_NAME = sh(returnStdout: true, script: "git --no-pager tag --points-at HEAD").trim()
  }
  agent {
...
```

4- Use Jenkins's `buildingTag` function to check whether commit has tag or not

```
...
  stage("Publish Release Artifact") {
    when {
      buildingTag()
    }
...
```

Answer (score -1):

I have been using soru's solution, but I had problems when I was building a branch that is tagged, so I tried this and it seems to work:

```
def boolean isVersionTag(String tag) {
    echo "checking version tag $tag"

    if (tag == null) {
        return false
    }

    // use your preferred pattern
    def tagMatcher = tag =~ /\d+\.\d+\.\d+/

    return tagMatcher.matches()
}

def String readCurrentTag() {
    return sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'echo ${TAG_NAME}').trim()
}
```

Comment: According to other answers, `buildingTag()` is checking for when the `TAG_NAME` environment variable is set, and here you are just using the `TAG_NAME` environment variable so theoretically you should just be able to use `buildingTag()` in the first place.